# Visual editor for PIL?

Tags: python, image, animation, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to visually edit images and generate Pillow code that will correspond to those edits, ala recording a macro? I'm interested in creating Pillow code that will do different image transformation and compositions but it is a pain to develop everything purely in code - the feedback loop of running the script to see if things are in the right place pixel-wise is really slow. Looking for a better tool.

Comment: What kind of operations are you looking to do?

Comment: Not for PIL, but there used to be a very powerful suite called AVS https://www.avs.com/tm-gs-avs5/#avs5-box that was a bit like Scratch https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tutorial=getStarted for image analysts. No idea what happened to it and I don't know anything similar for PIL, or OpenCV.

Comment: There is a GUI for `libvips` called `nip2` which is kind of like Excel for images... https://github.com/libvips/nip2

Comment: you tagged "animation". are you looking for a video editor (adobe premiere) or an effects/compositing program (adobe after effects)? or something like Figma? -- you're specifically asking for recommendations, and how to avoid programming. I don't think your question is a good match for SO.

Comment: @Andrew It seems Python [can run C++ functions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/calling-c-functions-from-python) so  maybe an option is to compile all [your required (pixel editing) functions](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/tree/main/src/libImaging) inside one big `.c` source file and later run them from Python to get their results where your Python code can show/update it in real-time.

Comment: I really don't think compiling anything is part of the question.